# golden ratio of a fraction

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math

This is a computational exercise, but I am looking to attempt on a calculation on a golden ratio. I am trying to compute that of the continued fraction for the golden ratio $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$, and I am starting from the definition of $(a+b)/a = a/b$.

Comment: Do you see Zelos's answer. Substitute $1+\frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{b}}$ for $\frac{a+b}{b}$ in $1+\frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{b}}$, then continue with this process.

Comment: I tried it but stuck/bogged down in the algebra. Can someone expand further?

Comment: @mary, notice that the number $\frac{a + b}{b}$ in the denominator  is the same as the expression Zelos started with.  Therefore, it can be replaced with $$1 + \frac{1}{\frac{b}{a}}$$ and $\frac{b}{a}$ can be replaced with $\frac{a + b}{b}$ so the process can be iterated.  You should obtain the infinite continued fraction $[1; 1, 1, 1, \ldots]$.

Answer (score 4):

Simple, you have
$$\frac{a+b}{b}=\frac{b}{a}$$
and
$$\frac{a+b}{b}=1+\frac{a}{b}=1+\frac{1}{\frac{b}{a}}=1+\frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{b}}$$
and the process continues onward.